# Spring Java Login without Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I moved to creating my proper login without security, and would like to know how to test if the result of an Hibernate query got a result or not cause now my managedbean login method always returns a SUCCESS result, wether the login is correct or not :

Managed Bean :

```
public String login (){
        try {
            getUsermanagerService().logUser(username, password);

            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ERROR;
    }
```

DAOImpl :

```
public UserData logUser(String username, String password) {


List<UserData> userList = new ArrayList<UserData>();
Query query = openSession().createQuery("from UserData u where u.username = :Username and u.password = :Password");
query.setParameter("Username", username);
query.setParameter("Password", password);
userList = query.list();
if (userList.size() > 0)
    return userList.get(0);
else
    return null;}
```

ServiceImpl :

```
public UserData logUser(String username, String password) {
    return getUsermanagerDAO().logUser(username, password);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic has error.

```
 try {
        getUsermanagerService().logUser(username, password);

        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When user aren't in DB, query will be empty and you will not have any exception. May be, you must check

```
if (getUsermanagerService().logUser(username, password) != null) return SUCCESS; else ERROR;
```

And if you want use information about 
authorized user, you must return User class and use it? But this is another story.